# Android Get latitude and longitude with location manager

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I'm trying to get the user location with location manager but the location always returns null. I also am asking to the user to turn on the gps.

This is my code:

```
   int permisioncheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    if(permisioncheck == 0){

        lm = (LocationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

        Location bestLocation = null;

        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location == null) {
                continue;
            }

            if (bestLocation == null || location.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                bestLocation = location;
            }
        }

        if(bestLocation == null){
            System.out.println("is NULL!");
        }
    }else{

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
```

I hope that someone could help me to find the error, thanks.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw what else I must add to my question ? practically it is all my code

Answer (score 3):

The "error" is that you are assuming that `getLastKnownLocation()` will return a `Location`. Frequently, it will return `null`. Use `getLastKnownLocation()` as a possible optimization, but otherwise you need to `requestLocationUpdates()`, then use the location in the `onLocationChanged()` method.

See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location/Classic) and [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) for more.