# Cannot get latitude and longitude from LocationManager (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps, locationmanager

I'm trying to use Location manager to get latitude and longitude of my current location. But whenever I press on "start", it just return me `cannot find location`. Does anyone know what caused this issue?Although GPS might not work on virtual device, but I tested the program with my actual device(Pocophone f1) which might not the issus. Other than that, I switch to mobile data it work for a second but it doesn't last long.

**Error:**
[image]

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sossystem">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SOSsystem">
        <activity android:name=".Admin_hospital"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Admin_bomba"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin_bomba"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SOSsystem.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Admin_police" />
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Register" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Java code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static  final int REQUEST_LOCATION=1;

    Button getlocationBtn;
    TextView showLocationTxt;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String latitude,longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button logout = findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);

        //Add permission

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        showLocationTxt=findViewById(R.id.show_location);
        getlocationBtn=findViewById(R.id.getLocation);




        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
                finish();
            }
        });


        getlocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                //Check gps is enable or not

                if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                {
                    //Write Function To enable gps

                    OnGPS();
                }
                else
                {
                    //GPS is already On then

                    getLocation();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void getLocation() {

        //Check Permissions again

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,

                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        else
        {
            Location LocationGps= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Location LocationNetwork=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Location LocationPassive=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (LocationGps !=null)
            {
                double lat=LocationGps.getLatitude();
                double longi=LocationGps.getLongitude();

                latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
                longitude=String.valueOf(longi);

                showLocationTxt.setText("Your Location:"+"\n"+"Latitude= "+latitude+"\n"+"Longitude= "+longitude);
            }
            else if (LocationNetwork !=null)
            {
                double lat=LocationNetwork.getLatitude();
                double longi=LocationNetwork.getLongitude();

                latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
                longitude=String.valueOf(longi);

                showLocationTxt.setText("Your Location:"+"\n"+"Latitude= "+latitude+"\n"+"Longitude= "+longitude);
            }
            else if (LocationPassive !=null)
            {
                double lat=LocationPassive.getLatitude();
                double longi=LocationPassive.getLongitude();

                latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
                longitude=String.valueOf(longi);

                showLocationTxt.setText("Your Location:"+"\n"+"Latitude= "+latitude+"\n"+"Longitude= "+longitude);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't Get Your Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //Thats All Run Your App
        }

    }

    private void OnGPS() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage("Enable GPS").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Did you add permissions for GPS in your AndroidManifest.xml?
Could you add it to your post?

Comment: Don't rely on `getLastKnownLocation()` but instead request location updates.

Comment: @Ascendise I added the manifest inside the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android getlastknownlocation returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689372/android-getlastknownlocation-returns-null)

Comment: I had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807604/get-location-updates-after-gps-enabled-by-user
My issue was that gps location is returned when there is an update to it. With a device, even if not moving, location always updates the last decimals due to inaccuracy and this very inaccuracy triggers the return.
However, in an emulator there is no such inaccuracy so lat and long are a fixed value causing to never have a return location. Enable location, change the location in the emulator settings and you should get a return with the new lat and long.